# What has happened to the World Phonotactics Database?

Tags: phonology, resource-request, phonotactics, online-resources

There was a resource named "World Phonotactics Database" once located at http://phonotactics.anu.edu.au/, but this location has gone. Searching for World Phonotactics Database on the web only brought up announcements and links to this now stale location.

Is the resource relocated to another place (which?)? Or is it completely discontinued and unavailable now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked with the maintainers. They tell me there is currently no official version of the phonotactics database online. However, they are still actively expanding it and there are plans to build a new interface, to be hosted at UC Berkeley, but the timeline is uncertain.