# Where can I find all of the consonant/vowel word formation formulas for a given language? And what is the name of this?

Tags: phonology, morphology, vowels, consonants

I'm new to linguistics. I've seen that there are `CVC` or `VVC` or similar structures presented in online resources (for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable)) to denote the possible combinations of sounds.

I want to find a complete list of them for a given language. I have no idea what to search.

For example, in a particular language two or three consecutive vowels might not occur at all.

What is this *thing* called? To formulate a language's words and sounds as Consonants and Vowels (or maybe other generalizations) and represent them as consecutive combinations of these letters.

And where can I find them?

Answer (score 2):

These sorts of rules (restrictions on possible syllables, what sounds can occur next to each other, etc) are called [phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics).

There is currently no good single resource to check this for any given language. There is the World Phonotactics Database in development, but currently it is not available online anywhere. For more information on that you can see this site question [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/44494/what-has-happened-to-the-world-phonotactics-database).

Comment: English phonotactics is very complicated, but many languages, like Japanese or Hawai'ian, have extremely simple syllable structures. And in still other languages, like Salishan, syllabification is extremely variable, since long clusters are tolerated.