# Universal Phonotactics Database

Tags: phonotactics

Is there a universal phonotactics database available online?

Comment: related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/44494/what-has-happened-to-the-world-phonotactics-database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

"Universal" in the context of language means "all languages". There isn't even a universal phoneme-inventory database. A phoneme inventory is the product of a lot of analysis of a language, whereby you can conclude that in Mongolian (a major national language), there are phonemes /u/ and /ʊ/ – this wasn't understood until the 90's. It requires many orders of magnitude more analysis to arrive at the distributional regularities that constitute a statement of "phonotactics". To this day, it is not definitely decided whether nonexistent sequences in English like "snin", "slill", "spep" are merely accidentally missing, or are they systematically excluded.

There *was* [a plan](https://pacificinstitute.anu.edu.au/outrigger/2013/02/15/world-phonotactics-database/) to have a large but not universal database, which did not materialize.